# Handle api requests on infinity scroll and laravel error 429

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Currently I am developing an app where the user can scroll infinite through products.
Frontend is vue, my backend is laravel which contains my pictures.
The image of the product is loaded via axios.get to my laravel api.

```
<v-card>
   {some other components}
<v-img :src="loadProductImage(product.nr)"
                        contain/>
  {some other stuff}
</v-card>
```

This, of course, only triggers when the rendered v-card is in the viewport.

This, however, lead me to another problem.
The infinity scroll loads 25 product informations (the images are not contained here as this would take too long) via pagination.
When a user decides to quickly scroll down that pagination call works flawless.
But this triggers an insane amount of image load requests is queued as well which results in error 429 "too many requests".
My other thought was to call a pagination request for the images as well. But this would also lead to around 25*60kB of data to be transferred (not that big but to me it is kind of disrupting when I see no images and suddenly 25 are displayed at once).

Is there any other elegant solution to this besides upping the throttle in laravel as this seems to be an "it works but not the way should be"-way.

Comment: go to your `RouteServiceProvider` and try commend out `configureRateLimiting` or increase limit there for more then 60 which is default, if this help you can disable it only for one route or for whole app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to add some condition, to only fetch next content if the previous request is finish. For example:

```js
async fetch() {
    if (!this.isFetching) {
        this.isFetching = true
        await httpCall()

        // optionally you may add some setTimeout here, to make sure
        // you don't stress your server.
        this.isFetching = false
    }
}
```

And for your image, I suggest you not get your product images using different httpCall, since it'll kills your server. Get images of your product via eager load, something like

```php
Product::with('images')->paginate();
```

then, display it using **[LazyLoad](https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-lazyload)** technique.

---

For better UX, you can add [Vue Content Loader](https://github.com/egoist/vue-content-loader). So user knows that the app is actually try to load next content.